# Android - List not binding to RecyclerView MvvmCross

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am fairly new to android and I am trying to bind a List I have in my ViewModel to a RecyclerView in my UI. I am using Xamarin and MvvmCross. I have the RecyclerView setup like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">


<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/menu_item"
    app:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my menu item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:MvxBind="Text Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly, my VM List is something like this:

```
 MyItems = new List<NavItem>
 {
       new NavItem { Title = "Option1" }
       new NavItem { Title = "Option2" }
 };
```

EDIT:

Here where I set the properties:

```
List<NavItem> _myItems;
    public List<NavItem> MyItems
    {
        get => _myItems;
        set => SetProperty(ref _myItems, value);
    }
```

and MyItem:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

I'm pretty sure it's setup properly; however, for some reason, it won't populate my recycler view. Did I miss something? any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change List to MvxObservableCollection and check

Comment: Tried it, still empty

Comment: paste your full Vm once

Comment: if it helps, I am getting this warning: MvxBind:Warning:  4.29 Unable to bind: source property source not found Property:Title on MainViewModel

Comment: Show me the setters of MyItems, and NavItem change as well.,

Public MvxObservableCollection<Navitem> MyItem {get {return MyItem} set {MyItem = value; RaisePropertyChange(() => MyItem}};

Public Class NavItem {
Public string Title {get;Set;}
}
see if the syntex matches

Comment: Updated the post to add those items

Comment: I will use the same code an update the solution soon.

Comment: Great! I'll keep an eye out

Comment: Can you share with us a bit more of your code? How are you navigating to the VM which contains the list? What kind of UI representation does the VM have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I had `xmlns:app="https:` instead of `xmlns:app="http:`